# inconsistency between format and probe-scsi-all outputs

Tags: solaris-10, sparc, format

my platform:
SPARC T4-1
solaris 10
Generic_150400-24 sun4v sparc sun4v

1 of the disk is seems different in the output of format when I am on console cli
even though relevant disk seems same as others in the output of probe-scsi-all output
what can be wrong with c0t5000CCA07058B9F0d0 below (first disk in output)?

I did see that in front panel disk led is green as others.

strange thing is that when I was doing solaris 10 installation from CDROM installation menu for ZFS 
also could not recognize the capacity of that disk, it shows 0 MB 
(I added below example from other box so disk name in installation menu is different)

```
# format
Searching for disks...done


AVAILABLE DISK SELECTIONS:
       0. c0t5000CCA07058B9F0d0 <HITACHI-H109060SESUN600G-A720-558.91GB>
          /scsi_vhci/disk@g5000cca07058b9f0
       1. c0t5000CCA070584ED8d0 <HITACHI-H109060SESUN600G-A690 cyl 64986 alt 2 hd 27 sec 668>  solaris
          /scsi_vhci/disk@g5000cca070584ed8
       2. c0t5000CCA070590CD8d0 <HITACHI-H109060SESUN600G-A690 cyl 64986 alt 2 hd 27 sec 668>  solaris
          /scsi_vhci/disk@g5000cca070590cd8
       3. c0t5000CCA070590E10d0 <HITACHI-H109060SESUN600G-A690 cyl 64986 alt 2 hd 27 sec 668>  solaris
          /scsi_vhci/disk@g5000cca070590e10
       4. c0t5000CCA0705836F8d0 <HITACHI-H109060SESUN600G-A690 cyl 64986 alt 2 hd 27 sec 668>  solaris
          /scsi_vhci/disk@g5000cca0705836f8
       5. c0t5000CCA0705893ECd0 <HITACHI-H109060SESUN600G-A690 cyl 64986 alt 2 hd 27 sec 668>  solaris
          /scsi_vhci/disk@g5000cca0705893ec
       6. c0t5000CCA0705955F0d0 <HITACHI-H109060SESUN600G-A690 cyl 64986 alt 2 hd 27 sec 668>  solaris
          /scsi_vhci/disk@g5000cca0705955f0
       7. c0t5000CCA07059468Cd0 <HITACHI-H109060SESUN600G-A690 cyl 64986 alt 2 hd 27 sec 668>  solaris
          /scsi_vhci/disk@g5000cca07059468c
Specify disk (enter its number): ^C

{0} ok probe-scsi-all
/pci@400/pci@2/pci@0/pci@f/pci@0/usb@0,2/hub@2/hub@3/storage@2
  Unit 0   Removable Read Only device    AMI     Virtual CDROM   1.00

/pci@400/pci@2/pci@0/pci@4/scsi@0

FCode Version 1.00.64, MPT Version 2.00, Firmware Version 9.05.00.00

Target 9
  Unit 0   Disk   HITACHI  H109060SESUN600G A720    1172123568 Blocks, 600 GB
  SASDeviceName 5000cca07059468c  SASAddress 5000cca07059468d  PhyNum 0
Target a
  Unit 0   Removable Read Only device   TEAC     DV-W28S-B        AT11
  SATA device  PhyNum 6
Target b
  Unit 0   Disk   HITACHI  H109060SESUN600G A720    1172123568 Blocks, 600 GB
  SASDeviceName 5000cca0705836f8  SASAddress 5000cca0705836f9  PhyNum 1
Target c
  Unit 0   Disk   HITACHI  H109060SESUN600G A720    1172123568 Blocks, 600 GB
  SASDeviceName 5000cca070584ed8  SASAddress 5000cca070584ed9  PhyNum 2
Target d
  Unit 0   Disk   HITACHI  H109060SESUN600G A720    1172123568 Blocks, 600 GB
  SASDeviceName 5000cca070590cd8  SASAddress 5000cca070590cd9  PhyNum 3

/pci@400/pci@1/pci@0/pci@4/scsi@0

FCode Version 1.00.64, MPT Version 2.00, Firmware Version 9.05.00.00

Target 9
  Unit 0   Disk   HITACHI  H109060SESUN600G A720    1172123568 Blocks, 600 GB
  SASDeviceName 5000cca07058b9f0  SASAddress 5000cca07058b9f1  PhyNum 0
Target a
  Unit 0   Disk   HITACHI  H109060SESUN600G A720    1172123568 Blocks, 600 GB
  SASDeviceName 5000cca0705893ec  SASAddress 5000cca0705893ed  PhyNum 1
Target b
  Unit 0   Disk   HITACHI  H109060SESUN600G A720    1172123568 Blocks, 600 GB
  SASDeviceName 5000cca070590e10  SASAddress 5000cca070590e11  PhyNum 2
Target c
  Unit 0   Disk   HITACHI  H109060SESUN600G A720    1172123568 Blocks, 600 GB
  SASDeviceName 5000cca0705955f0  SASAddress 5000cca0705955f1  PhyNum 3

{0} ok

─ Select Disks ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

  On this screen you must select the disks for installing Solaris software.
  Start by looking at the Suggested Minimum field; this value is the
  approximate space needed to install the software you've selected. For ZFS,
  multiple disks will be configured as mirrors, so the disk you choose, or the
  slice within the disk must exceed the Suggested Minimum value.
  NOTE: ** denotes current boot disk

  Disk Device                                              Available Space
  =============================================================================
  [X]    c0t5000CCA07057269Cd0                            572308 MB
) [X]    c0t5000CCA070583C94d0                            572308 MB
) [X]    c0t5000CCA0705862A4d0                            572308 MB
) [-]    c0t5000CCA070588C7Cd0                                0 MB
  [X]    c0t5000CCA07058D0A0d0                            572308 MB  (F4 to edit
) [ ]    c0t5000CCA07058F494d0                            572308 MB
  [ ]    c0t5000CCA070590FD0d0                            572308 MB
  [ ]    c0t5000CCA0705940C0d0                            572308 MB
```

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this before, and in my experience, is because one of two reasons:

1. The disk is slightly different than the others. It has a slightly different disk geometry, or already has some kind of weird or corrupt meta information that prevents Solaris from reading the disk geometry correctly
2. The disk is bad, and is failing, or will fail soon.

If the disk is not already in use, I'd recommend replacing it with another. I would recommend doing a format/analyze read (or an analyze write if there is no useful data on it) to do a thorough test. If any errors are found, replace the disk.

If this is a disk that a vendor (Oracle?) replaced, note that they don't always use the exact same disks, even though they may be the same brand or size. Even if the label matches, the internals of the drive may be different. I've run into this a lot in the past.